# Raspberry "blocks" after some work

Tags: pi-3, power, jessie-lite, cpu

I've installed plex server and samba on my raspberry pi 3.

My configuration is:
- jessie-lite
- Micro sd samsung, 16GB, class 10;
- Power: 5V - 1.5A;
- an usb dongle for keyboard;
- external 3,5" hdd, 1TB, with alimentation;
- connected via LAN;
- the last updates.

As title, sometimes, Raspberry it blocks or turn off itself, when I try to convert a movie with plex convertion. And then only the red led is turned on.
I think that after some work, Raspberry has problems.

With Samba it's all okay: I've try to trasfer about 8GB of data, without problems and with a 8-11MB speed.

This is my first Raspberry and I don't know what I can do. Some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Raspberry Pi 3 have a recommendation of a 2.5A power supply. And movie conversion = high CPU load = high power consumption.

Ref.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md

Comment: Thanks! I've tried with 3A power supply and it seems to work.
The power is:
input: AC 100-240V 
output: 3,6-6,5V/3A 6,5V-9V/2A 9V-12V/1,5A 
Is it okay?